# Handling special characters (UTF-8 encoding ? ) in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a source table mySchema.FRUIT which gets loaded from a flat file using db2 import command.

For fields with special characters, I am using below unix command for proper conversion before inserting in FRUIT table:

```
 iconv -c -f UTF8 -t iso8859-15 $MY_DATA_DIR/FRUIT_TEMP.dat > $MY_DATA_DIR/FRUIT_FINAL.dat
```

FRUIT_FINAL.dat is what gets loaded into mySchema.FRUIT table.

Now, I have a spring batch program which loads a destination table mySchema.PROCESSED_FRUITS from mySchema.FRUIT table. So it is a simple DB to DB spring batch program.

However, I am getting error for the fields containing special characters:

For e.g. a column is a country column with value as "SÃ?O PAULO"

When this column is being inserted by itemWriter into the destination table, I am getting error as:

The value of a host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN statement is too large for its corresponding use.
 Code: -302

For above example, the column in question is same in all ways in both the source and destination table i.e. 
VARCHAR(50)

How can I handle such special characters in a Spring Batch Job ?